# custom validation with jsvalidate

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm using [jsvalidate](http://www.jsvalidate.com/docs/) and I want to require some fields only when the user selects a yes (Sí) on my form here:
[image]

A required validation field on jsvalidate is implemented writing `class="jsquerired"` on the select element. How can I make `class="jsquerired"` appear if the user clicks "Sí" on my select?

Example:`<input class="jsrequired jsvalidate_email texto" name="emailRecomendado" type="text" size="30"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem jsvalidate comes with conditional validation out of the box, so you will probably have to come up with a custom validation class for those fields that checks if "yes" was selected -- and if it was, return true (validation passed) if the field is not empty.